# detailsview > on insert > password field should save md5 hash of it instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, passwords, detailsview

i am having problems with the detail view control in visual studio.

[image]

as you can see, it is a simple insert, but in the database there is a column name password salted hash which i plan to use to save the hash of the password, however, i want people to be able to here input the actual PASSWORD and than have it make a hash and save it.

please, tell me how? i presume it is possible, but am lost.

i tried all sorts of things, like converting a field to a template and figuring it out from there, but that got me nowhere - or at least i did not figure it out. also watched tutorials of detailsview control, but such example was not used. is there a way?

thnx

id' prefer the visual way, if it exists, simple because there are other similar instances where i'd need this, but if code is the only way, i'll take that as well - with code i am unsure how to influence the insert behaviour.